# Disable WooCommerce checkout payment for specific user meta data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

My customer wants to enable for some specific customers to pay afterwards via invoice.
So i've added an extra field in the user profiles, where he can select yes/no.
This field works fine and saves properly.

Depending on the choice:
no = default webshop behavior and customer needs to pay direct.
yes = customer can order items without paying, he'll get an invoice later on.

Also tried different payment methods, but they are available for everybody, i only want them for specific users.

Now i've tried based on that field in the functions.php to add a conditional filter like so:

```
if (esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'directbetalen', $user->ID ) ) == 'no') {
    add_filter('woocommerce_cart_needs_payment', '__return_false');
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work?

I want payment to be skipped when the field is set to `no`.
Else proceed as normal and customer needs to pay.

Comment: The filter _should_ work based on the documentation. Have you tested the `if` conditional in a way that  yields the expected result?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Seems the whole author meta isn't available in functions.

Comment: Have you tried [`the_author_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_author_meta/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using WordPress `get_user_meta()` function, try the following :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_payment', 'disable_payment_for_specific_users' );
function show_specific_payment_method_for_specific_users( $needs_payment ) {
    if ( get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'directbetalen', true ) === 'no' ) {
        $needs_payment = false;
    }
    return $needs_payment;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried your code, but it disables payments for everyone.
I tried to replace 'disabled_payments_for_specific_users' with the function name.
For the user with 'no', the payment stuff keeps loading (not selectable), while a normal user can pay.

Comment: Sorry for that, it works like a charm! Thanks a lot!